# how do i select and update info in an xml file

Tags: c#, xml

so i know how to load the the data from the selected gridview in to text boxes but how do i make it so it will update the selected place info and not make a new place in the file and also delete a selected place from file if i want to.

this is how i currently load to the datagrid

```
ds.ReadXml("Database.xml");

string filter = "";
filter = "userdata" + " LIKE '*" + "u" + "*'";
DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
dv.RowFilter = filter;
dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
dataGridView1.Columns[4].Visible = false;
```

and how i load in to the text boxes depending on which is clicked

```
if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
{

DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
Nametb.Text = row.Cells["name"].Value.ToString();
Locationtb.Text = row.Cells["Location"].Value.ToString();
Infotb.Text = row.Cells["Info"].Value.ToString();
dayvisitcb.Text = row.Cells["Dayvisited"].Value.ToString();

}
```

this is my xml

```
<root>
  <place>
    <Name>home</Name>
    <Location>x-292 z 277</Location>
    <Info>home</Info>
    <Dayvisited>10</Dayvisited>
  </place>
  <place>
    <Name>town</Name>
    <Location>x 990 z-2485</Location>
    <Info>gas station</Info>
    <Dayvisited>12</Dayvisited>
  </place>
  <place>
    <Name>crossing</Name>
    <Location>x 90 z-2998</Location>
    <Info>working stiff</Info>
    <Dayvisited>11</Dayvisited>
  </place>
</root>
```

this file will contain random names and will contain hundreds of places. but so far i can load places to grid,select a place and the details go in to text boxes for editing but then i can only add it to the list and not just update the selected place or delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better leverage [DataBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding). That will do all the heavy lifting, without the need of any coding yourself. You only have to Read and Write the XML file in your dataset.

First in your project add an new item, DataSet (found in Data category), name it Database. Add a DataTable by right clicking on the desgin surface, choose Add > DataTable.  Name your DataTable *place*. Next add in your table the 4 columns Name, Location, Info and Dayvisited.
In the Properties of the Dataset, empty the field Namespace.
When you're done this will be your result:

[image: dataset]

Build the project.

Open your Winform in Design mode.
From the Toolbox drag from the category Data the components BindingSource, BindingNavigator, DataGridView and DataSet on your form.

For the DataSource choose the Typed dataset `database` you created in the previous step.

Click the bindingSource and set the property DataSource to *database*. Set DataMember to *place*.

Click the bindingnavigator. Set the property Bindingsource to *binsdingSource1* (assuming you left its default name untouced ).

Click the datagridview. Set the property DataSource to *bindingSource1*.

Add the Textboxes for each field. For each textbox in the properties open the DataBindings category and for the Text property select *bindingSource1* -> Name (repeat for the other properties).

Add a button to your form to Load the dataset. This is the code that goes in its click event:

```
database2.ReadXml("Database.xml");
this.button2.Enabled = true;
button1.Enabled = false;
```

Add a button to your form to Save the dataset. This is the code that goes in its click event:

```
database2.WriteXml("Database.xml");
```

When you're all done this is what your Project should look like:

[image: project overview]

When you run it and click the load button, select records, add a new record with the navigator and click save, this will be your result:

[image: example]

Comment: this works but is not the method i want to use. is there a way to make it so i can do the update to a button as the bindingnavigator + is just bindingSource1.AddNew(); can i make it bind to a string instead of a textbox ? as that would be more flexible. so when i addnew it updates from the strings that i gave value to. if this makes sence.

Comment: You can hide the binding navigator, and the textboxes then make your own button that calls bindingSource1.AddNew() and then fill the TextBox.Text with the strings you had in mind. You can't bind to a string value directly as a string is immutable, you bind to the properties of the instance of an class. In my example that is the datagrid and the textboxes. Beyond that you're on your own.